# Error de Makefile recipe for target 'Prueba1.exe' failed

Tags: c++

El error ocurre cuando intento compilar el código con funciones de la librería graphics.h.
Si incluyo la librería no pasa nada pero cuando ejecuto initwindow me arroja errores en main.o y makefile.win.

> C:\Codigos\C++\Dev\main.o main.cpp:(.text+0x3d): undefined reference to `initwindow'.

> C:\Codigos\C++\Dev\Makefile.win   recipe for target 'Prueba1.exe' failed.

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\bin\ld.exe  i386:x86-64 architecture of input

Me marca que el error se encuentra ahí

```
$(BIN): $(OBJ)
    $(CPP) $(LINKOBJ) -o $(BIN) $(LIBS)
```

Mi código es este

```
#include <iostream>
#include <graphics.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    initwindow(400,400,"Progama1");
    getch();
}
```

Esto se que funciona por que en un computador viejo de win7 32bit me funcionaba perfectamente y ahora en win10 64bit no he podido avanzar

Comment: Por lo que busque, no es una librería que este incluida o en su defecto debe activarse dependiendo del compilador, puedes mirar este [link](http://chuwiki.chuidiang.org/index.php?title=Gr%C3%A1ficos_Usando_graphics.h)

Y el error básicamente te indica eso, _referencia no definida para initwindow_

Comment: Lo intentaré aunque soy algo experimentado con la librería, nunca me hizo falta cuando graficaba en win7 32bit

Comment: Eso probablemente paso por que el entorno ya estaba configurado en tu maquina anterior.

Comment: Realmente fue hace tanto que es probable que lo haya configurado pero no me acuerdo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Descarga los siguientes archivos en los directorios mencionados:

*Aquí supongo que instalaste Dev-Cpp en* `C:\Dev-Cpp`

[http://www.cs.colorado.edu/~main/bgi/dev-c++/graphics.h](http://www.cs.colorado.edu/%7Emain/bgi/dev-c++/graphics.h)   Directory:> C:\Dev-Cpp\include
[http://www.cs.colorado.edu/~main/bgi/dev-c++/libbgi.a](http://www.cs.colorado.edu/%7Emain/bgi/dev-c++/libbgi.a)  Directory:> C:\Dev-Cpp\lib

Crea un nuevo proyecto C ++ y establece "Opciones de proyecto-> Parámetros-> Linker" como

```
-lbgi
-lgdi32
-lcomdlg32
-luuid
-loleaut32
-lole32
```

e intenta ejecutar este código de muestra; luego busca el código que publicó anteriormente.

```
#include<graphics.h>
 
int main( ){
        initwindow( 700 , 700 , "MY First Program");
        circle(200, 200, 150);
        getch();
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Gracias pero ya lo tenia puesto, encontré la solución y no le encuentro sentido pero funciona

Answer (score 1):

Al parecer el error estaba en iniciar en modo gráfico pero no sabia como, entonces después de una noche de investigar a distintas personas que instalaban la librería hubo una que añadió unos archivos en la carpeta

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\Templates

Que se llaman

> 6-ConsoleAppGraphics.template

> ConsoleApp_cpp_graph.txt

Luego de iniciar el proyecto como aplicación gráfica funcionó sin problemas
dejo el link por si lo quieren
https://www.mediafire.com/file/s1rjaedp4j1n7tx/Graphics_in_Dev_C%252B%252B.rar/file